# Fragment is not showing up

Tags: android

I m trying to make a simple fragment example where one fragment will show an Article List and the other will show detailed article.
This is my main activity class-

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }       
}// end class
```

This is the main layout file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.ArticleList"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.ArticleDetails"
            android:id="@+id/viewer"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my two fragment class for ArticleList and ArticleDetails

```
public class ArticleList extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.articlelist, container, false);
        }

public class ArticleDetails extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.articledetails, container, false);
    }
    }
```

I have also TWO XML layout files(containing a textview) for both articleList, ArticleDetails fragment. But the app has stopped working. What have I missed here? Pls help thanx.

Comment: What do you mean by ~"the app has stopped working"?  Did you put breakpoints in onCreateView methods and debug them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Package name inside the code

```
<fragment android:name="com.abc.def............./>
```

.Thanks to you I know that we can do it.

Comment: But do u think everything else is OK, mean the code..my min sdk version is api-11

Comment: UPPPSSS...my package name is com.example.articlefragment , SO I changed the class name accordingly. com.example.articlefragment.MYCLASSNAME and it worked. BTW, in another example it used class="com.example.MyclassName" in fragment tag to refer to the class. Whats is the difference ? THANX A LOT

Comment: No mention. Glad you have done it. Actually <fragment android:name=""> takes the path of the Fragment class in which you show  or return the view. So the path with package name should be correct.